# Core dump size is 0 for non root user

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, coredump

For some reason, core dump is generated with 0 bytes size in Kubernetes pod running with non root user.
If I modify the pod to run as root, this works fine.
Is there a way to get this to work for non-root user?

This is my setting on node, these propagate to pods as /proc is mounted as hostpath

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx /]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
/tmp/%h.%t.core

[root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx /]# cat /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
2
```

As a non-root user, I can create and modify files under this directory "/tmp".
But when I try to generate a core dump with "kill -6 ", core dump is generated with size 0

```
-rw-------. 1 root root         0 Aug 11 17:26 app1-cluster1.core.8
```

If I modify my k8s deployment to run as root user (i.e. runAsUser: 0), I can generate coredump successfully

```
-rw-------. 1 root root 219246592 Aug 11 18:12 app1-cluster1.core.8
```

Comment: Check with `ulimit` what limits are in place. Adjust with e.g., `ulimit -c unlimited`.

Comment: @Robert ulimit for core dump is already set to unlimited
all these return "unlimited" for both root and nonroot users
ulimit -c
ulimit -Hc
ulimit -Sc